# Extensions for Sharepoint Products in TFS 2010 issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Good day, first i have to say that i'm mexican so, excuse my not so good english.

Well, i have an error that i don't found the solution, i have already installed my TFS 2010 in a server with Windows Server 2008 R2, in another server with the same OS i have Sharepoint 2010, so i want to connect TFS to my sharepoint, when i try to configure "Extensions for SharePoint Products" at start the wizard i receive an error:

"TF254051: The verification process found one or more errors. Before you can continue, these errors must be fixed. For more information about these errors see the log file."

and i cannot configure the extension.

I searched in the net without any good result..

Thnx for read me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check link:
http://blog.hinshelwood.com/integrate-sharepoint-2010-with-team-foundation-server-2010/

Please post error from latest file on TFS server C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs

Comment: haha damn! i've installed both systems and integrate! i did installed the extension in the sharepoint server :$ thnx so much!!